# Cannot query from Firebase for my React Native app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, jsx

It seems I can retrieve *all* my data from my Firebase Realtime Database with the following:

```
let itemsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('/');

itemsRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  let item = Object.values(data);
  this.setState({item});
});
```

But when I try to query with specific parameters instead of just retrieving all the information, I always end up with this error:

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback.
>
> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

This is how I'm trying to query information... literally following the documentation, and somehow my code works when I retrieve all information but not when the only change I make is adding a query?

```
let itemsRef = firebaseApp.database().ref('/');
    
itemsRef.orderByChild('roundedBPM').equalTo('100').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  let item = Object.values(data);
  this.setState({item});
});
```

Is anyone else having problems querying from Firebase or am I doing something wrong?

This is how my data is structured on Firebase:

[image: Firebase data screenshot]

Comment: So the error as you may guess is because of Object.values(data) and data is null. Question is do you have the data with specified query parameters in database? somewhere you are trying to query what doesn't exist. Before going ahead, first try console.log your data and see what you see. 
You could easily use chrome dev tools console for it as well

Comment: Also, perhaps add your data structure, it may give a better understanding of what you are trying to do or the problem.

Comment: Also, if you are new I would encourage you to look into Firestore as well since there are limitations with real time database which Firestore addresses.

Comment: Also posted on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1167

Comment: @TheeBen I edited my question and posted an image of my Firebase data structure. I definitely do have some songs in my database with a "roundedBPM" of 100, so why is the data null? Thanks so much!

Comment: It looks like you are using a string to compare in your query but the value in your database is a number. Have you tried removing the quotes from `equalTo('100')`?

Comment: the string/number nature of your query and data seem to be the issue. try equalTo(100) and not ('100')

Comment: Thank you so much!! That worked! Finally god I've been trying to get this to work for days!

Answer (score 0):

I would try initializing firebase in dbConfig.js for instance like so:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

let config = {
    apiKey: "XXXXXXX",
    authDomain: "XXXXX",
    databaseURL: "XXXXX",
    projectId: "XXXXX",
    storageBucket: "XXXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXXX"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase;
```

I would import firebase where it's:

```
import firebase from './dbConfig.js' 
let itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('/');
itemsRef.orderByChild('roundedBPM').equalTo('100').on('value', (snapshot) => {
  let data = snapshot.val();
  let item = Object.values(data);
  this.setState({item});
});
```

Note: OrderByChild the element roundedBPM needs to be a direct child to the root path '/' if it's a nested child you could do something like this:

```
let itemsRef = firebase.database().ref('/users');
itemsRef.orderByChild('roundedBPM').equalTo('100').on('value', (snapshot) => {
      ...
});
```

Note: if you are setting equalTo() roundedBPM when it's a number and not a string you wouldn't get back any data. Make sure you use the correct type of data.

I hope this will help!